# Book for generating functions(non-calculus)

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Could someone please recommend a book or some resource to study about generating functions-one that doesn't require calculus, but should be adequate for contest problems (AIME, USAMO, IMO, etc.) on combinatorics and counting.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: ? The idea of generating functions is to use basic calculus to solve enumerative problems....

Comment: The AoPS text: Patrick -- Intermediate Counting and Probability (2007) has an excellent (precalculus level) chapter on generating functions, and the entire book is oriented to math competition-related theory and problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generatingfunctionology by Herbert Wilf is probably a good book for you, its a very readable introduction to using generating functions to solve enumerative problems/prove identities.

Calculus is mostly used formally, as in take formal derivatives, the chain/product rules etc.

It does go into more serious analytic aspects in some parts, but those aren't needed for the enumerative stuff, from what I recall.

Also, its a free download from his website, and has a decent amount of exercises.

Comment: Thanks sir. Would it be beneficial if I took up calculus now?

Comment: From my (albeit limited) experience, you don't really need to understand it for generating function stuff in combinatorics, but knowing the ideas can be really helpful for a better understanding. (and you definitely need the symbolic stuff, like formal differentiation etc)